# Temporarily change directory for single batch-file command

Tags: windows, batch-file, working-directory

In shell-scripting if I need to run a command from a directory I can us a subshell to ensure I return to the original context:

```
(cd temporary/new/directory ; command)
# now I am still in original directory
```

Can this be done in Windows batch-files (or cmd-files)

Doing the same in batch-files leaves me in the new directory.

I can do:

```
pushd temporary\new\directory && command && popd
```

But the popd is dependent on the success of `command`.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you invoking your "batch-file" or "cmd-file"? If you put a cd command into a shell script and execute that script (not source it), the current working directory of the calling shell will not change.

Comment: Just to be clear this is referring to windows batch-files.

Comment: Its a script which runs a bunch of commands in different parts of a directory tree.  Some of the commands only operate on the current-directory.  Returning to the original directory helps simplify the data that drives the script.  Are you suggesting making a separate batch-file for each directory that i need to make calls in?

Comment: As I recall, you referred to shell scripts and didn't mention Windows in your original question, so I incorrectly assumed that you were using a Unix-like system. Now I understand.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realise I wasn't clear (although I think 'batch-file' was a hint :-p)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you do:

```
pushd \windows && foobar && popd
```

you'll be left (as you state) in the \windows folder. Try:

```
pushd \windows & foobar & popd
```

and you should find yourself back where you started.

Comment: Ah, so single ampersand is the equivalent of semi-colon in sh. That's perfect.  (and a reference: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

Comment: It's good to remember that `cd`/`pushd` sometimes fails (if the directory doesn't exist, for example). `pushd \windows && (foobar & popd)` may be more reliable

Answer (score 26):

By default, Windows batch files are run in the parent shell's context (which is unusual for Unix users, where an explicit `source` is needed, but was the only possibility in MS-DOS). This means directory changes and environment variables affect the original interactive shell too.

Put `setlocal` at the top of your script to make it run in its own context – you can safely use `cd` inside the script then.

Comment: Thanks, This sounds like what I need - I'll check it when I get access to a Windows machine.  Would that affect sub-commands using parentheses?

Comment: @Greg: It seems that `(` `)` only group commands together, but still run them in the parent context. `(setlocal & cd foo & bar)` will not work; instead `pushd foo && (bar & popd)` would be needed.

Answer (score 7):

As grawity previously mentioned, `pushd \windows && (foobar & popd)` would work better than `pushd \windows & foobar & popd` because the latter may fail if there is no such directory.

Also, using `setlocal` and `endlocal` allows you to have multiple local environments, so for example you could have:

`setlocal`

`cd dir`

`command`

`endlocal`

Now you would be back in your original directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cd -` to go back to the previous working directory. And use `;` instead of `&&`, then the subsequent commands won't be dependent on the success of previous commands.

```
$ pwd
/etc
$ cd /var ; pwd ; cd -
/var
$ pwd
/etc
```

Comment: I've updated question to clarify I'm asking about windows batch/shell scripting.  I know how to do it under a sh-like shell :)

Comment: As BillP3rd pointed out the equivalent of ';' in batch-files is '&'.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Your use of forward slashes made me think it was UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

I applaud grawity’s suggestion to put `setlocal` at the beginning of your batch script, but I would add the fact that you can have multiple, nested, `setlocal` / `endlocal` blocks, so a more relevant answer to the question might be

> `@echo off`
>   `setlocal`
>   `cd`*`dir1`*
>     `...`
>   `setlocal`
>   `cd`*`dir2`*
>   *`command`*
>   `endlocal`
>   `:: Now I am back in`*`dir1`*
>     `...`

And, of course, if you want the command to be executed only if the `cd` to *`dir2`* is successful, say `cd`*`dir2`*`&&`*`command`*.

Note that the `setlocal` / `endlocal` block creates a localized environment, so any variables that you set or change in such a block will revert to its previous value after the `endlocal`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current directory into a variable.  Change and change back depending on the return value of the command.   BTW, %CD% returns your current DIR.